# cannot debug into my DbContext derived class code using Entity Framework (ver 4.3.1) code-first

Tags: entity-framework, debugging, mstest, code-first, breakpoints

Here is my solution setup using VS 2012 Ultimate:

I have a project (e.g. MyDomainModel) containing all the business domain types using POCO classes. I have another project (e.g. MyEntity) referring to the MyDomainModel project and has the derived DbContext class (e.g. MyDbContext) implementing custom business logic (e.g. for automatic time-stamping when inserting and modifying data) in the SaveChanges method.

I have another mstest based project (e.g. MyEntity_Tests) which will test the derived DbContext (e.g. MyDbContext) with known seeded data as part of the database initialization.

My problem is that when debugging the test, the breakpoint set on the MyDbContext's c# code is not hit. However if I put lines such as Debug.Print("xxx") in the file and debugging the same test, the test output will contain those expected output "xxx".

I know that Entity Framework runtime will generate proxy dll behind scene to wrap those dlls (e.g. MyDomainModel.dll). However not being able to debug my own code as in MyDbContext is really a big problem to me. Do other people have the similar problem when using EF code-first and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Set the breakpoint on a line in the derived DbContext class start debugging and hover the mouse over it to see why it is not hit. Most likely symbols are not loaded. When debugging go to loaded modules window right click on your assembly and you can check where VS tried loading symbols from. You can also load your symbols manually. Note that if symbols don't match the assembly you need to rebuild your project to get up-to-date symbols. Another reason why a breakpoint is not hit may be because your source code does not match the assembly. You can uncheck the checkbox in Settings->Debugging to enable debugging on sources that don't match assemblies but debugging like this is painful and counter-productive. Again rebuilding should help. I am assuming you are trying debugging Debug versions of your assemblies and not Release ones.

Comment: I have rebuilt all and known the symbols and code are in sync.                Interestingly, the exact same solution debugs fine in VS 2010 (Note: VS 2012 and VS 2010 solutions are compatible to each other), i.e. breakpoints behave as normal.

Comment: Maybe in VS2010 you have a symbol path you don't have in VS2012? Have you tried force load symbols?

Comment: I added extra debug symbols settings to VS 2012 (copied from my VS 2010 settings). The problem still stays. To be clear, it's not that any breakpoint in MyDbContext not hit, it's just that the ones that I am interested in stopping are not hit. Also I noticed that in modules window, debugging in VS 2010, there is a module named like "EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-MyEntity" loaded, which does not appear in VS 2012 debugging session.